# ios: How to add blur effect on Uiimage using pinch gesture

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiimage, uislider

I am trying to add blur effect on `UIImage` Like photo editing apps have functionality. For example Aviary app setting focus on particular part of image.
**Note** 
I want to set focus on image in circle shape not rectangular.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: Please give a link to what you are talking about.

Comment: @iosDev82 like all photo editing apps have function to focus on image by adding blur effect in rounded circle when user tapped od pinch on image. image  started gradually blurred. I am not able to find that kind of implementation.